# IN MVC 4 how do you pass data to your controller without using the query string

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, parameters

We have a form that displays user information for a list of users. We have an action link to go to a details view for the user to update information. Our application is a mixture of ASP.Net 4.0 and MVC. We normally use encryption to mask variables we use in the query string, but MVC chokes when we attempt to encrypt the query string. We are using the Microsoft Enterprise 5.0 Cryptogrophy class.
How would we go about either encrypting the query string or passing the data without using the query string at all?
We are using MVC 4 with Razor.

We are currently doing something like this:
    @Url.Action("Edit", "User", new {id = user.Id}

BTW, I am new to MVC, so there may be an easy answer to this that I am just not aware of.

It would be really nice if we could not use the query string at all.

Comment: How about use Ajax post of your data in JSON format to controller?

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer: POST. Use a form or an AJAX call to send the values as POST data, and have a controller method named the same as the existing one, but marked with the `[HttpPost]` attribute (also, mark the existing one as `[HttpGet]`). The arguments for this new POST method can be whatever you like; they may get turned into strings when they get POSTed (especially if you use AJAX) but MVC is smart enough to convert them back again provided they're named the same. So, a form that's something like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "User", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "mainForm" }))
{
    <input id="userId" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" />
}
```

will correspond neatly to a controller method like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int userId)
{
    //do whatever
}
```

provided you've got the routes registered properly. If your GET method is working, then the same route will work here, as long as it doesn't do anything problematic with URL parameters.

That same method will also accept the submission from an AJAX call that looks something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("Edit", "User")',
    data: { userId: @user.Id },
    success: function (data) {
        //do whatever
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with anaximander, but if you're going to that much effort to secure the query string information, forms just move the information to HTML fields instead of query string parameters. If you need to keep your existing implementation you could look into inheriting from the default ModelBinder, and provid your own custom implementation to convert from encrypted query string to unencrypted query string before you hand it over to the base class's implementation.